# Duplicate questions in listing if searched by tag and sorted by votes

Tags: bug, search

Whenever I am trying to search using the tag and after that if I sort them with votes, then it shows the duplicate question and hence makes it difficult to find unique questions.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't actually duplicate results; it's showing you both questions *and* answers. Notice one set starts with "Q:" and the other with "A:" (the excerpt is different too), both questions and answers show the question title though, which is where the confusion comes from.

You can limit the search to only questions or answers by appending `is:question` or `is:answer` (or the shorter form `is:q` or `is:a`).

Comment: Gotcha, but why there is answers in listing if i am searching the question alone.

Comment: You're not searching questions alone, searches return both questions and answers by default

Comment: I think the problem here is that searches that are identical to an existing tag *should* redirect you to the tag page (which does only show questions). I'm not sure why that isn't hapenning

Comment: @DS9 FYI [Searching for a tag inconsistently redirects to the tag page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/305889)

Answer (score 3):

The result is fine, there is not a bug at all.

You can filter the questions alone, by adding [`is:q`](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=isro%20is%3aq) or `is:question` to the search term.

For answers alone, by adding [`is:a`](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=isro%20is%3aa) or `is:answer` to the search term.

You can find more advanced help futures in this link : https://space.stackexchange.com/help/searching